# How to find where a LiveData is observed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, observable, android-livedata

I am studying a project with LiveDatas on Android Studio (Java). I would like to know if it exists an Android Studio option to see where a particular LiveData is observed in the project, to see all the objects that are been notified and in which method.

Comment: Normally your LiveData objects are exposed via a method in your ViewModel. Android Studio has a "Find Usages" option if you right-click on that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best solution, to me, is to find usages of the particular 
LiveData's *getter* method of *viewModel*, then see when the LiveData is observed after *get*.

Answer (score 3):

you can access by typing `.observe` into **Find in Path**(cmd + shift + f in Mac):

sample live data observing:

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer {})
```

Comment: Sorry I was not sufficiently clear in the question... now I have edited

Comment: there is no AS option like you mentioned in AS to understand which live data is observed currently

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Android studio can't give you such "runtime" information. The best you can do, is to call LiveData's `hasActiveObservers()` returns true if there are active observers, or `hasObservers()` returns true if there are any observer.